# Wordpress navigation <ul> additional fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress

are there any chances to make output of `wp_nav_menu` look like:

`<ul class="..." data-uk-nav="">`?

Whole thing is about adding that `data-uk-nav` filed to `<ul>` element, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you already have any code?

Comment: You can do that using custom Nav Walker Class. But that would be critical. So, you can do that using jQuery: `$('ul').attr('data-uk-nav', 'value');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-uk-nav="">%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, the menu is created by calling wp_nav_menu. wp_nav_menu, has lots of parameters, one of which is the wrapper for the menu.

```
$args= array(
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-uk-nav="">%3$s</ul>',
    ...
);
wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Where the items_wrap value is just the default with your "data-uk-nav" attribute added.